# Newbie in python : pyodconverter with Apache OpenOffice 4 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, openoffice.org

I don't know anything about Python, and I need to convert documents with pyodconverter on windows (XP and 7). I use the simple example given here : http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org2.4\program\soffice.exe" -headless -nologo -norestore -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager
"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org2.4\program\python" DocumentConverter.py test.odt test.pdf
```

it works like a charm with path to soffice.exe from openoffice 3, but with openoffice 4 i get this message :

```
ImportError: No module named uno
```

and this goes on with every other module imported (`from os.path import abspath, isfile, splitext from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue
from com.sun.star.task import ErrorCodeIOException
from com.sun.star.connection import NoConnectException`)

BUT if i copy and execute DocumentConverter.py in the same directory as python.exe, it works. So it must be just a path issue.

- I can't call DocumentConverter.py from this dir, it must be called from another dir
- but i can modify DocumentConverter.py or add other files in same dir.

I see that the directory structure between OpenOffice 3 and 4 has changed but no clue why it works with 3 and not with 4. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the search path when using DocumentConverter.py with OpenOffice 4.

python.exe from OpenOffice 4 seems to use relative search path instead of absolute ones, that's why you get an error when executing DocumentConverter.py from another directory than the one, where OpenOffice 4 is installed.

I could solve this problem by adding the following lines of code before the 'import uno' command in DocumentConverter.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program")
```